# jython error "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0""

Tags: python, jython, execfile

i tried to run a python script using Jython,

```
from javax.swing import JButton,JFrame
def action():
    execfile(r"E:\stack.py")
frame = JFrame("window")
button = JButton("button", actionPerformed = action)
frame.add(button)
frame.show()
```

But it's showing error:

`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" TypeError: action() takes no arguments (1 given)`

Here i'm not passing any arguments to action function!

where am i going wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The button press always passes an event. Anything you set to JButton.actionPerformed needs to handle it to work properly.

Try this:

```
from javax.swing import JButton,JFrame
def action(event):
    execfile(r"E:\stack.py")
frame = JFrame("window")
button = JButton("button", actionPerformed = action)
frame.add(button)
frame.show()
```

This can be quite useful once you're aware of it. Suppose you have two buttons bound to the same event and you need to know which one was pressed.

```
def show_which_button_was_pressed(event):
   sender = event.getSource()
   print sender.getText()
```

As an aside, you're also not allowed to send more than event to an actionPerformed method. If you were to want to you can look at a [workaround in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084679/jython-swing-passing-more-than-self-and-event-on-a-button-press).